# Preventing "One Hours" "One MInutes" "One Days"

Tags: php, time

If my code looks like:

```
if($seconds < 60)
  $interval = "$seconds seconds ago";
else
 if($seconds < 3600)
     $interval = floor($seconds / 60) . "minutes ago";
else
    if($seconds < 86400)
         $interval = floor($seconds / 3600) . "hours ago";
    else
         $interval = floor($seconds / 86400) . "days ago";
```

How would I get rid of it saying stuff like:

1 Days ago.
1 Years ago.
1 Minutes ago.
1 Hours ago.

Thanks :)

Comment: Is your application localizable?

Comment: you can ever use a "generic" plural: day(s), hour(s), minute(s), and so

Answer (score 7):

Can be done quite concisely with a ternary operator:

```
if($seconds < 60) {
    $interval = "$seconds second" . (($seconds != 1) ? "s" : "") . " ago";
} else {
    if($seconds < 3600) {
        $minutes = floor($seconds / 60);
        $interval = "$minutes minute" . (($minutes > 1) ? "s" : "") . " ago";
    } else {
        if($seconds < 86400) {
            $hours =  floor($seconds / 3600);
            $interval = "$hours hour" . (($hours > 1) ? "s" : "") . " ago";
        } else {
            $days = floor($seconds / 86400);
            $interval = "$days day" . (($days > 1) ? "s" : "") . " ago";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: $interval = "$minutes " . (($minutes > 1) ? "minutes" : "minute") . " ago"; a little less repetition :-)

Comment: @Philippe Gerber - LOL@Karma - I wish SO called it that.

Comment: I applied your suggested edit, Phillipe, and made it even a bit shorter :)

Comment: And I even messed it up the first time. Silly me!

Comment: @Philippe go a step further: $interval = "$minutes minute" . (($minutes > 1) ? "s" : "") . " ago";

Comment: @Paul Fisher - Nice one!, who says there's no team spirit on SO?

Comment: Just to be pedantic you could change it to
abs($seconds) != 1 so that negative numbers would work.
-1 second, -2 seconds :P

Answer (score 7):

If your app is international and using the gettext extension, you can do something like this:

```
sprintf(ngettext('%d minute', '%d minutes', $amount), $amount);
```

You can create a wrapper function to it:

```
function pluralize($singular, $plural, $num) {
  return sprintf(ngettext($singular, $plural, $num), $num);
}
```

This is the best way imo.

Answer (score 3):

Yet another solution.

```
if($seconds < 60)
  $interval = "$seconds second";
 else
   if($seconds < 3600)
     $interval = floor($seconds / 60) . " minute";
   else
     if($seconds < 86400)
       $interval = floor($seconds / 3600) . " hour";
     else
       $interval = floor($seconds / 86400) . " day";
$interval .= (reset(explode(" ", $interval)) != 1 ? "s" : "")." ago";
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$time = "120";
$array = array("second" => 1,
               "minute" => 60,
               "hour" => 60,
               "day" => 24,
               "year" => 365);
$old_time = 0;
$old_type = false;

// Loop through each type
foreach($array as $type => $seconds)
{
    // Divide
    $time = floor($time/$seconds);
    // If it went into a value lower than 0, stop dividing
    if($time < 1)
    {
        $time = $old_time;
        $type = $old_type;
        break;
    }
    else
    {
        // Continue dividing.
        $old_time = $time;
        $old_type = $type;
    }
}
if($time == 1)
{
    $interval = $time . " ". $type . " ago";
}
else
{
    $interval = $time ." " . $type . "s ago";
}
echo $interval;
```

This divides through all the possible time types, and gives one that doesn't turn it into a fraction. By separating the number value from the type, we are then able to test if the number is == 1, and correct the word.

Comment: as long as you don't go international, yes. doesn't work in like all languages ;-)

Comment: Just updated it with something a little different. Took awhile though.

Comment: Just updated it something more expandable. You could do centuries very easily :)

Answer (score 1):

```
if ($interval < 60) {
    $unit = 'Second';
} else if ($interval < 1440) {
    $unit = 'Minute'; $interval /= 60;
} else if ($interval < 86400) {
    $unit = 'Hour'; $interval /= 1440;
} else {
    $unit = 'Day'; $interval /= 86400;
}
$interval = intval($interval);
$interval = "$interval  $unit" . ($interval == 1 ? '' : 's') . " ago";
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a generic PHP snip for getting strings like "1 month, 2 weeks and 30 seconds ago".

```
$timeUnits = array("month" => 2592000,
                  "week" => 604800,
                  "day" => 86400,
                  "hour" => 3600,
                  "minute" => 60,
                  "second" => 1);

$tmpSeconds = $seconds;

$timeAgoStrings = array();

foreach ($timeUnits as $name => $numOfSeconds) {
   if ($seconds > $numOfSeconds) {
      $val = floor($tmpSeconds / $numOfSeconds);
      $agoStr = ($val > 1) ? $name."s" : $name;
      $timeAgoStrings[] = "$val $agoStr";
      $tmpSeconds = $tmpSeconds - $val; // cut the used time units off our tmpSeconds variable
   }
}
//check if we have more than one string - in case we do then we will pop the last val and add an "and" prefix before the last val instead of a comma
if (count($timeAgoStrings) > 1) {
   $lastString = array_pop($timeAgoStrings);
   $timeAgoStr = implode(", ",$timeAgoStrings)." and $lastString ago";
} else {
   $timeAgoStr = $timeAgoStrings[0]." ago";
}
```

Comment: when giving it -1 please describe why

Answer (score -1):

Do the math.

```
else if($seconds < 120)
     $interval = "1 minute ago";
else if($seconds < 172800)
     $interval = "1 day ago"
```

etc.